# what is the difference between these two expressions

Tags: probability, logistic, binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

What is the difference between

$$ \frac{exp^{-\beta_j}}{1+exp^{-\beta_j}}$$

and

$$ \frac{exp^{\beta_j}}{1+exp^{\beta_j}}$$

From an application perspective ?

Comment: The second one can be written $\frac{1}{1+exp^{-\beta_j}}$ so is $exp^{\beta_j}$ times the first

Comment: 1. Conventionally $\exp$ is a function and $e$ is a number - they're not interchangeable; I think you either mean to write $e^{\beta_j}$ (talking a power of a number) or $exp(\beta_j)$ (taking a function of an argument). $\:$ $\:$ $\,$ 2.  Note what happens when you multiply the numerator and denominator of the first expression by $\exp(\beta_j)$. Can you see that the two expressions are complements (i.e. they add to 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually none, since you can simply flip the sign on your coefficient.

There is a difference of course if during model fitting you constrain your parameter to be (say) nonnegative. Or if you regularize it towards a value that is nonzero, or towards zero but with some asymmetric regularization technique. Or if you work with priors that are not symmetric around zero (which is actually just a special case of regularization).

Comment: I suspect you might have read "$1/(1+\exp(\beta_j))$" for the second expression rather than what it actually says.

Comment: @Stephan Kolassa, Thank you Stephan, Whuber, Glen, Henry this gives me something to think about what I am doing.